# How to get MAC address for both Wireless and Ethernet using C#?

Tags: c#, networking, network-programming

I want to get MAC address of both Wireless network adapter and the ethernet adapter of a computer by using C#.
I came across NetworkInterface.GetPhysicalAddress method (http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/system.net.networkinformation.physicaladdress%28v=vs.110%29.aspx) but I am not sure whether it will return both the address (wireless/ethernet) or any one address.
Can someone clarify this and can you also provide a code snippet which is actually capable of fetching both the addresses if they exist in the computer (i.e. if both the adapters are present in the computer)

Comment: `I am not sure whether it will return both the address` - why not try and see?! `can you also provide a code snippet` - why not try example from your linked documentation Examples section?

Comment: It will get you the MAC address of the network adapter it refers to, i.e. you need an instance of `NetworkInterface` for each adapter. The MSDN article you link to shows you how to get the mac adressess of all the network adapters in the machine.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Just try

```
var networks = System.Net.NetworkInformation.NetworkInterface.GetAllNetworkInterfaces();
```

Below attached array printout, notice NetworkInformationType field.

[image]